# How to refresh parent JQ grid without refreshing the parent page from child popup window in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, javascript, model-view-controller, jqgrid

I am using window.open to open a child pop-up in my MVC page for when closing the popup i should refresh my parent Jquery Grid without refreshing the whole page is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reloadGrid to refresh the grid and can use the onbeforeunload event to trigger the grid refresh like the code given below, substitute your grid ID and window URL with yours ID and URL

```
var myWindow = window.open('your_url')
myWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){ 

$("#your_grid_id").trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);

}
```

Comment: What is the `[{current:true}]` doing for you in the reload?

Comment: @Mark In his case I think it is not needed, I copied from one of my grid page. current:true will retain the selection. It was a mistake there was some other parameters like page, I removed all those but forgot to remove this

Comment: Cool, I was just curious as I hadn't seen that parameter before and didn't seem to find it on the wiki.